# Regarding Dirac equation heuristic formulation

Tags: operators, dirac-equation

So in the Wikipedia Page of [Dirac equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation) we are presented with this equation
$$\nabla^2 - \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} = \left(A \partial_x + B \partial_y + C \partial_z + \frac{i}{c}D \partial_t\right)\left(A \partial_x + B \partial_y + C \partial_z + \frac{i}{c}D \partial_t\right).$$

My question is: Is the multiplication of two first-order equal to second-order as presented above?

Comment: The two expressions on the left and right side of the equation can be equal, but only if the constants $(A,B,C,D)$ meet certain requirements.

Comment: Yeah Ik, but what about the differentials operator, shouldn't it be quadratic in first order (left side )

Comment: I don't understand. You have second order differential operators on both sides.

Comment: this is the part i don't quite get  $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} =  \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} or  (\frac{\partial}{\partial x})^2$.

Comment: Both are valid notations for the same thing.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1550600/   , this is the source of my confusion

Comment: The linked question does not apply to your question here. Here you have $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)^2 f=\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2}f$. Note the placement of $f$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112611/discussion-between-test00alone-and-thomas-fritsch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt always use a test function to find out what differential operators might do, as an example (assuming $A,B,C$ and $D$ do not depend on position and do not commute):
$$\begin{align}
\left(A\partial_x + B\right)\left(C\partial_x + D\right)f(x) &= \left(A\partial_x + B\right)\left(C\partial_x f(x) +D f(x)\right) \\
&= A\partial_x \left(C\partial_x f(x) +D f(x)\right) + B \left(C\partial_x f(x) +D f(x)\right)\\
&= A C\partial_x \partial_x f(x) + A D\partial_x f(x) + B C\partial_x f(x) + BDf(x)\\
&= A C\partial^2_x f(x) + A D\partial_x f(x) + B C\partial_x f(x) + BDf(x)
\end{align}$$

as you can see operating with a differential operator of order 1 on another differential operator of order 1 produces a differential operator of order 2. Perhaps the notation is what is misleading to you:
$$\partial_x^2 = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)^2 = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$$
is a second order derivative, while
$$\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2 = (\partial_x f) (\partial_x f)$$
is a square of a first derivative.